# perl-selenium: like() or $sel->like()?

Tags: perl, testing, selenium

Perl-Selenium also provides the standard methods of Test::More such as ok(), like(), is(), etc , also as object methods, e.g. `$sel->like()`.

($sel is the selenium perl object)

Should these object methods be used at all? Which one is preferred?

I am puzzled because like() and $sel->like seem to behave differently in places.
Here I assume text is indeed found on the page.

```
like( $found, qr /$text/, "found '$text' on page" ) ; # WORKS FINE

 # DOES NOT WORK, ERROR:    "doesn't look much like a regex to me."
$sel->like( $found, qr/$text/ , "found '$text' on page")
```

So it seems the pure like() method is preferable to $sel->like()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like [Test::WWW::Selenium](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Test%3a%3aWWW%3a%3aSelenium) does not itself provide `like` method, but rather many methods like `title_like` or `text_like`.

That gives us either

```
like( $found, qr /$text/, "found '$text' on page" );
```

or

```
$sel->text_like('id', qr/$text/, "found '$text' on page");
```

**Edit:** There is `like` method available in [Test::WWW::Selenium](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Test%3a%3aWWW%3a%3aSelenium), but when dumped, it looks like this:

```
sub {
    my $tb = 'Test::More'->builder;
    return $tb->like(@_);
}
```

it means that by calling as `$sel->like(...)` you are adding one extra parameter (`$sel`) to the method call. The method is remnant of `Test::Builder` inheritance and it likely not supposed to be used directly.

Comment: text_like() needs a locator id.  $sel->text_like("id", qr/$text/, "found")

Comment: Yes there is a pure $sel->like() method. I can call it, and I can also see it using the "Intellisense" Feature of the Eclipse Perl Editor E-P-I-C. Test::WWW::Selenium uses Test::Builder internally and the AUTOLOAD mechanism to add the text_like methods to $sel at runtime. text_like is mapped to get_text() of WWW::Selenium